# Group rows by unique ID with data from multiple columns in a single row in Oracle

Tags: oracle, merge

I've searched countless posts regarding my scenario, but can't seem to find an answer to achieve my desired results. I may not be asking the question correctly, which may be why I cannot find the answer.

I am looking for a way to group results by GRPID into a single row and display the results across multiple columns.

**Query**

```
SELECT GRPID, TYPE, NAME, TID, DATE
FROM TABLE1 AS S
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS D ON D.TID = S.TID
WHERE 
S.GRPTYPE = 'MEDIA'
AND S.GRP_ID IN ('1234','5678')
AND D.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
AND D.TYPE IN ('TALENT', 'MANAGEMENT')
```

**Current Results**

```
GRPID   Type        Name            TID     Date
1234    Talent      Jim Halpert     6259    1-Nov-05
1234    Management  Michael Scott   1411    1-Dec-00
5678    Talent      Dwight Schrute  8732    4-Mar-04
```

**Desired Results**

```
GRPID   Type_1  Name_1          TID_1   Date_1      Type_2      Name_2          TID_2   Date_2
1234    Talent  Jim Halpert     6259    1-Nov-05    Management  Michael Scott   1411    1-Dec-00
5678    Talent  Dwight Schrute  8732    4-Mar-04    null        null            null    null
```

I sincerely appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Comment: The point here is that you're trying to build a query with a variable number of resulting columns; this is not easy both to do and to handle (how to fetch values from a query without knowing the structure?). You could try to search something like "pivot" or "dynamic pivot"

Comment: What is the purpose to have such results? Dynamic columns are possible with dynamic SQL only (or `PIVOT XML`), but it should be consumed and parsed to different columns outside the SQL

Comment: The objective here is to group everything into one row so that I can easily merge it into another report. I thought I was dealing with only a maximum of two rows per GRPID, but it appears as though it can vary from 0-4. Therefore, it looks like I'll simply have to export the data and manually manipulate it to make it work with my final report. I appreciate the responses, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed types as ('TALENT', 'MANAGEMENT') only, You can use dynamic pivot here.

```
SELECT GRPID,
       'Talent' AS Type_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN D.TYPE IN ('TALENT') THEN Name END) AS Name_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN D.TYPE IN ('TALENT') THEN TID END) AS TID_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN D.TYPE IN ('TALENT') THEN Date END) AS Date_1,
       'MANAGEMENT' AS Type_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN D.TYPE IN ('MANAGEMENT') THEN Name END) AS Name_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN D.TYPE IN ('MANAGEMENT') THEN TID END) AS TID_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN D.TYPE IN ('MANAGEMENT') THEN Date END) AS Date_2
  FROM TABLE1 AS S
 INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS D ON D.TID = S.TID
 WHERE S.GRPTYPE = 'MEDIA'
   AND S.GRP_ID IN ('1234','5678')
   AND D.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
   AND D.TYPE IN ('TALENT', 'MANAGEMENT')
 GROUP BY GRPID;
```